# CSS Grid custom layout creation

Tags: css, grid

After hours of spending time trying to configure this thing, I couldn't get to correct answer about making these 'custom' grid layouts. I tried on my own but didn't get even close to it.

I am trying to make a layout provided in the picture. If someone could help me I would appreciate it a lot!

[GRID LAYOUT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaShX.jpg)

Comment: Where's your HTML, and your best attempt at CSS? What went wrong? *How* did it go wrong? Please read both the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines; we're not here to write your code for you: we're here to *help*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to get you started:

```css
body {margin: 0}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.box {
  padding: 20px;
  background: gray;
}

.first {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.fourth {
  grid-area: span 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box first">first</div>
  <div class="box second">second</div>
  <div class="box third">third</div>
  <div class="box fourth">fourth</div>
  <div class="box fifth">fifth</div>
</div>
```

Adjust it to your needs.

Hope it helps.